# Toggle jquery is not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using a function like I want to show just one tab at one like if I click others will hide and I also want to toggle the open tab too.

The `.show()` JQuery just appear on first first tab not others.

**JQuery :**

```
$('#toClick').click(function() {
    $('#toShow').hide();
    $(this).parent('#hideShow').find('#toShow').toggle();
});
```

**HTML :**

```
<span id="hideShow">
  <span id="toClick">tab 1</span>
  <span id="toShow">Tab 1 content</span>
</span>


<span id="hideShow">
  <span id="toClick">tab 2</span>
  <span id="toShow">Tab 2 content</span>
</span>


<span id="hideShow">
  <span id="toClick">tab 3</span>
  <span id="toShow">Tab 3 content</span>
</span>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`id` should be unique in same document change the duplicate ones by a general `class`, check example bellow :

```
<span class="hideShow">
    <span class="toClick">tab 1</span>
    <span class="toShow">Tab 1 content</span>
</span>

<span class="hideShow">
    <span class="toClick">tab 2</span>
    <span class="toShow">Tab 2 content</span>
</span>

<span class="hideShow">
  <span class="toClick">tab 3</span>
  <span class="toShow">Tab 3 content</span>
</span>
```

Then use class selector `.` :

```
$('.toClick').click(function() {
    $('.toShow').hide();
    $(this).parent('.hideShow').find('.toShow').show();
});
```

Hope this helps.

---

Comment: I already do that in this toggle is working but I can't hide the showed span.

Comment: done your method but now I can't hide the showed span

Comment: `$('.toShow').hide();` will hide all spans with class `toShow`.

Comment: I have create a fiddle so you can see what I am trying to solve   http://jsfiddle.net/BGSyS/748/

Comment: it looks fine, try to describe please more clearly what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: yes it is working fine but now in the end one tab element will be remain open. I want to have a option that I can close all by clicking anywhere in body or the tab titles with .toclick class.

Comment: And that not appear anywhere in the OP? How you expect that i can solve that?

Comment: I know that this is not in the OP. I want you to guide me to solve this problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102031/discussion-between-qarar-and-zakaria-acharki).